# TestNG Parallel Tests are going in Deadlock

Tags: selenium-webdriver, maven-2, testng

I have prepared a framework using selenium having parallel execution using the TestNG , i am generating the testng.xml file through code where in setting the parallel keyword to "tests". My tests are running fine but after the result are generated the build /JVM never terminates it goes into the deadlock .After debugging the code I found that the below line marked with **  is causing the issue of deadlock.

```
private Runnable getTask() {
    boolean timedOut = false; // Did the last poll() time out?

    for (;;) {
        int c = ctl.get();
        int rs = runStateOf(c);

        // Check if queue empty only if necessary.
        if (rs >= SHUTDOWN && (rs >= STOP || workQueue.isEmpty())) {
            decrementWorkerCount();
            return null;
        }

        int wc = workerCountOf(c);

        // Are workers subject to culling?
        boolean timed = allowCoreThreadTimeOut || wc > corePoolSize;

        if ((wc > maximumPoolSize || (timed && timedOut))
            && (wc > 1 || workQueue.isEmpty())) {
            if (compareAndDecrementWorkerCount(c))
                return null;
            continue;
        }

        try {
            Runnable r = timed ?
   **workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) :**
                **workQueue.take();**

            if (r != null)
                return r;
            timedOut = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException retry) {
            timedOut = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help in case ..

```
<    Thread [main] (Running)
    Thread [TestNG] (Running)   
    Thread [TestNG] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [Exec Default Executor] (Running)     
    Daemon Thread [Exec Stream Pumper] (Running)    
    Daemon Thread [Exec Stream Pumper] (Running) >
```

Test case script

```
    @Test public void Test_test() {
 try { 
////code/// 
driver.close(); 
} catch (Exception err) { 
System.out.println(err.getMessage()); 
Fail(err.getMessage()); 
}finally{ 
Closereport(); 
driver.quit(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the test code where you are seeing this issue ? You have basically shared `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#getTask` code and without context, its hard to decipher where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Not exactly where i can tell you m getting this but always the last thread goes into the deadlock. Please find the below of my test class files

Comment: @Test
      public void Test_test() {
   try {
   ////code///
   
   driver.close(); 
   
  } catch (Exception err) {
   System.out.println(err.getMessage());
   Fail(err.getMessage());
  }finally{
   Closereport();
   driver.quit();
  }
  }

Comment: Thread [main] (Running) 
Thread [TestNG] (Running) 
Thread [TestNG] (Running) 
Daemon Thread [Exec Default Executor] (Running) 
Daemon Thread [Exec Stream Pumper] (Running) 
Daemon Thread [Exec Stream Pumper] (Running)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the test code there.

Comment: added the test case code .. please let me know in case anything else you require. I am stuck with this everything running fine but need to close the build forcibly

Comment: Its still not very clear as to where could the bottle neck be. Couple of more questions. Why are you using `driver.close()` instead of using `driver.quit()` ? What does `Closereport()` do? How are you ascertaining that it's a deadlock ? I believe you need to have 2 threads involved to simulate a deadlock condition. But you state that its always the last thread. So am guessing that its perhaps that the last thread gets into a blocking call and never returns. Have you tried figuring out which call in your test code stalls ?

Comment: To answer the your questions .. Closereport is generating report from extent report class nothing much. which got generated successfully ,, My tests are running parallel and same class is executed with different set of data & browser

Comment: public static void park(Object blocker) {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        setBlocker(t, blocker);
        UNSAFE.park(false, 0L);
        setBlocker(t, null);
    }             my thread goes into UNSAFE.park and never returns

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan please look into the above comment

Comment: Can you please create a trimmed down version of your test code and share it ? You are just pointing at code in JDK and that doesn't help a lot. You haven't shown your complete tests as well. Hard to decipher with such bits and pieces of information.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan in case you want i can share the project in gdrive so that you can take a look at it and point where things are going wrong

Comment: I would suggest that you post it on GitHub or bitbucket and share the link. Am not sure if sharing a gdrive link is something people would want to open.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan   https://github.com/bhatnagars/Crossbrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the code to remove the deadlock , using synchronisation

Answer (score 1):

Like I suspected, the problem with stalled threads is due to your bad integration with ExtentReports. You would need to fix that. Perhaps you can refer to documentation [here](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#examples) to get some samples.

Apart from that, you may want to fix these general anamolies that I observed in the code that you shared.

1. Remove static variables from your code. You have a lot of statics and this is going to cause problems when you are running tests in parallel.
2. You have a sub-classed `RuntimeException` but the class doesn't seem to have anything related to exceptions.
3. Your `WebDriver` instance management in the test classes should make use of `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` in order to ensure that the browsers are properly cleaned up after use.
4. Please try following maven folder structure conventions so that it's code readability is better (Since people are used to the general folder structure of `src/main/java`/`src/test/java` (for source code) and `src/main/resources`/`src/test/resources` (for resources)